# Wicket insert/update/delete database table

Tags: mysql, wicket

Hi I am pretty new to wicket but I have been looking around for an example that show's how I can get data from a table in my database and then edit that data on a grid view in wicket and the changes being saved back to my database.

[image]

As you can see I tried doing it this way but it looks pretty bad and not very user friendly if the user has to go click edit every time to make a small change is there perhaps a better way to do this?

My goal is to make a time sheet where users will receive there specific time sheet when logging in and be able to edit is as they please like a excel time sheet almost.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the 'library' example:

```
http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/library/
```

Comment: That is what I all ready have but I am struggling with the connection to the the database "retrieving the specific users information and populating it onto the web page and then sending the changes back to my database." @svenmeier

Comment: Then the problem probably lies with your data access layer and in any case can only be answered if we see your code.

Answer (score 1):

Wicket is HTML presentation library. The buttons and form submits done in the wicket forms will trigger the logic that will modify your base.

You need a data access technology for this, its can be:
- an ORM like hibernate,
- a SQL generation library like JOOQs
- or you can write directly you hown SQL and pas it to database JDBC connection...